# Generate getter/setter JavaDoc from XSD with jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jibx

I am using `jaxb-maven-plugin` to generate Java code with XML bindings from XSD files. While it works generally great, the JavaDoc of the generated setters and getters are missing the documentation from the `xs:annotation /xs:documentation`.
I even started to write my own jaxb plugin; but even within such plugin I don't seem to be able to access the element's annotation.

Is there a straight forward way to do this? The `org.jibx`'s `jibx-maven-plugin` seems to be doing this out of the box, but I would like to be able to use the jaxb-maven-plugin's extensions and more up to date dependencies.

**Example extract of the XSD:**

```
<xs:complexType name="Some_Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Some_Field" type="BoolType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Some documentation</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
```

**POM extract:**

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on 4.0.1 version of the `org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin`.

This version includes update to [4.0.4 jaxb-ri](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/releases/tag/4.0.4-RI).
This 4.0.4 jaxb version includes the fix of [issue #1708](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/1708) : add javadoc from xsd documentation tags.

In the meantime, if you're using simple case usage of the plugin, you can try providing jaxb-xjc 4.0.4 as dependency of the plugin with the following change :

- `addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings` should be set to false (due to fixed also done in jaxb-ri (issue [#829](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/829))

Another possible solution is to use the following xjc plugin from CXF with the `Xjavadoc` flag :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-javadoc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great workaround, thank you; however, this adds the doc to the getter, and only a "see also" reference to the setter; can this also be configured?

Comment: This is the default behaviour and not configurable in xjc. Setter is not always present by the way. You could give a try to the cxf-xjc-javadoc plugin (added to answer)

Comment: If the default behaviour in 4.0.4 xjc is not enough, you can create an issue in github jaxb-ri to add an option to duplicate javadoc in setters